# After creation of JNI_CreateJavaVM, cout no longer works?

Tags: java, c++, g++, java-native-interface

I'm pretty new to c++, and I started of with jni. When I use the `JNI_CreateJavaVM` method, `cout` doesn't work(at least with the g++ build command I'm using)

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\include -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\include\win32 -LC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\lib -ljvm
```

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    options[0].optionString = (char*) "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

    // jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    cout << "It Works!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The commented line, when added results in the `cout` not working at all and I'm not sure why.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger? I'd imagine `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is crashing for some reason. For example on my machine your code shows exactly these symptoms if the jvm dll is not available

Comment: Looks like a `Windows` specific issue. On `macOS` this code works perfectly well (regardless of wether the line is commented out or left uncommented). Java - `1.8.0_251`. Are you sure that your code doesn't crash on line: `jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);`

Comment: @AlanBirtles i tried setting up the debugger on windows, but get a completley different problem where nothing happens for cpp.

Video Here - https://youtu.be/zB1zemDGhO0

Comment: Yep, `c0000135` indicates a missing dll, you need to have the jvm dll available on your path